# convert a date time string into a DateTime object to update in Sharepoint list DateTime field

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am just trying to update my Share Point list column of type Date Time.

I have a string in which I have a date in below format

**Friday, January 09, 2015 1PM**

now I want to convert this string into a Date Time object so that I can be able to update my Share Point List column which is of type Date Time in below format,

**1/9/2015 1:00 PM**

FYI I am using JSOM, so all my code is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can send as it is and parse it in dot net sharepoint.

string date = "Friday, January 09, 2015 1PM";

DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(date);

or any format like

DateTime.Parse("Friday, January 09, 2015 1PM", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

---

or if you want in JS it will be

var current= "Friday, January 09, 2015 1PM";

var splitDate = current.split(",");

var splitMonthName = splitDate[1].trim().split(" ");

var month = getMonthFromString(splitMonthName[0]);

var day = splitMonthName[1];

var year = splitDate[2].trim().split(" ");

var myDate = month+"/"+ day+"/"+year[0];

function getMonthFromString(mon)

{

return new Date(Date.parse(mon +" 1, 2012")).getMonth()+1

}

Comment: what about getMonthFromString() method , can you share it also